# Convergence of coordinates to zero

Tags: functional-analysis, vector-spaces, normed-spaces

Consider a normed finite-dimensional vector space $V$ with some norm $|| .||$

Say a sequence of vectors in this vector space $v_m \rightarrow 0$ where $0$ is the zero vector.

Let $\{b_1,b_2,\ldots,b_n\}$ is a basis for $V$.

Therefore $v_m = \sum_{i=1}^{n} c_i ^m b_i$ for some scalars $c_i$

I am trying to prove that $\forall m$ the sequences $\{ c^m_i \}_{i=0}^{\infty}$
converge to the scalar $0$.

This seems like an 'obvious' theorem, but I am having difficulty proving it. 
Obviously some triangle inequality has to be used here but I don't know how.
Using both the inequalities $ | ||x||- ||y|| |\leq ||x-y|| \leq ||x|| + ||y||$
on $||\sum_{i=1}^{n} c_i ^m b_i || < \epsilon$ does not give me an upper bound
on each of the $c^i_m$ sequences.

Any hints?

Comment: Consider using inner product

Comment: But this is a normed space. No inner product is given. A vector space with a norm need not have an inner-product , is that correct?

Comment: ok forget about it (as an advice, if it had an inner product considering $(v_m|b_j)$ and Cauchy Schwarz would give the answer)

Comment: Do you know that in finite dimensional spaces, all norms are equivalent? If you do, just use the sup norm.

Comment: Aha! Perfect! Thank you :-D

Comment: @xavierm02 Suppose V were infinite dimensional. Would this still hold true? Ofcourse in that case we would still have a finite linear combination of the infinitely many basis vectors

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do that by first showing that norms are equivalent in a finite dimensional space (see https://math.stackexchange.com/a/345661/10385) and then you have $M\in \Bbb R, \| \cdot\|_\infty \le M\|\cdot\|$ so if for a sequence of vectors $\left(v_n\right)_{n\in \Bbb N}$, $v_n\underset{n\to +\infty}{\longrightarrow}0$ for the norm $\|\cdot\|$, that is $\|v_n\|\underset{n\to +\infty}{\longrightarrow}0$, you also have $\|v_n\|_\infty\underset{n\to +\infty}{\longrightarrow}0$ and since $0 \le |c_i^n| \le \|v_n\|_\infty\underset{n\to +\infty}{\longrightarrow}0$, $|c_i^n|\underset{n\to +\infty}{\longrightarrow}0$ so $c_i^n\underset{n\to +\infty}{\longrightarrow}0$.

---

And no, it doesn't work in infinite dimensional spaces.

Take $\Bbb R\left[X\right]$ the space of polynomials.

Take $\forall P \in \Bbb R\left[X\right],\left\|P\right\|=\int\limits_0^1 \left|P(t)\right|\space dt$

And $\left(\left(1-X\right)^n\right)_{n\in \Bbb N}\in \Bbb R\left[X\right]^\Bbb N$

$\left(\left\|\left(1-X\right)^n\right\|\right)_{n\in \Bbb N}$ is decreasing and bounded below so it converges to $l$. We also have $0\le l$.

$\forall \varepsilon > 0,\left\|\left(1-X\right)^n\right\|=\int\limits_0^1 \left|\left(1-t\right)^n\right|\space dt=\int\limits_0^\varepsilon \left|\left(1-t\right)^n\right|\space dt+\int\limits_\varepsilon^1 \left|\left(1-t\right)^n\right|\space dt \le \varepsilon +\int\limits_\varepsilon^1 \left|\left(1-t\right)^n\right|\space dt\underset{n\to +\infty}{\longrightarrow}\varepsilon$

So $\forall \varepsilon >0, l \le \varepsilon$ which means $l=0$.

So $\left(1-X\right)^n\underset{n\to +\infty}{\longrightarrow}\Bbb 0$

But $\left(1-X\right)^n = \sum\limits_{k=0}^n {n \choose k} 1^{n-k}\left(-X\right)^k = 1 + \sum\limits_{k=1}^n {n \choose k} \left(-X\right)^k = 1 - X\sum\limits_{k=0}^{n-1} {n \choose k+1}\left(-X\right)^k$

So since we know that $\Bbb R\left[X\right]=\Bbb R_0\left[X\right] \oplus X\Bbb R\left[X\right]$, in the canonical basis $\left(X^n\right)_{n\in \Bbb N}$, the first coordinate will remain 1.

Comment: Wow that is very clever! Thank you very much

Comment: @smilingbuddha: I couldn't find a counterexample so I asked my teacher and he gave me one. I edited my answer.